# is RELP exist outside of RSYSLOG protocol if so were?

Tags: linux, logging, tcp, rsyslog

is RELP exist outside of RSYSLOG protocol if so were?
i want to know if the relp protocol has more to it then a protocol that has been writen to the rsyslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Philippe's answer: [Logstash](http://logstash.net) also has a [RELP input](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.2/inputs/relp). You can find the implementation here (for version 1.2.2):

https://github.com/logstash/logstash/blob/v1.2.2/lib/logstash/util/relp.rb

Answer (score 1):

The RELP protocol has been designed by Rainer Gerhards, the author of rsyslog.
The only implementation I know of is [librelp](http://www.librelp.com/), which is used by rsyslog.